# How to use awk to delete rows from one csv, some values in a column of which matche the other csv column?

Tags: csv, awk

I have been trying to delete rows (records) from a csv in which entries in a specific column match the entries in the other csv.

The csv structure is roughly like this:

1.csv

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
sasdf,3432,fjkdk,fjjof,1234
efvr,4565,fhjs,dihi,9999
asa,234,rgs,fkjf,0102
aaa,456,jfvv,dofh,4565
ths,7865,fhjf,fhks,3212
```

2.csv

```
Col1    
1234
3212    
0102
4565
```

So as you can see, there are some values in col5 of 1.csv that appear in col1 of 2.csv
I want to use awk to delete the rows (records) from 1.csv that match col1 of 2.csv

So the output would look like this:

3.csv

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
efvr,4565,fhjs,dihi,9999
```

Here is the awk script I used:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{array1[FNR]=$1};NR>FNR{array1[FNR]!~$5}' 2.csv 1.csv > 3.csv
```

It did not work.

Comment: I'm not sure why you thought changing you input files completely would be helpful. When asking a question post representative input only.

Comment: Oh I'll take care of that going forward..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($5 in a)' 2.csv 1.csv
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
efvr,4565,fhjs,dihi,9999

$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($5 in a)' 2.csv 1.csv > 3.csv
```

Comment: I got confused if it will read $5 unless I change the NR==FNR condition as it is from the second input file. Thanks again!