# Remove data from column using data from another file and deleting the row

Tags: csv, awk, grep

I have several files:
file 1:

```
1    2    3     4  5     6
ALA, 002, 2fv9, H, N,   O6   
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, CA,   C20  
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, CA,   O6   
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, N,   O6   
ALA, 00G, 3fuj, N, CB,   C2   
ALA, 00G, 3fuj, N, CB,   C3   
ALA, 00G, 3fuj, N, N,   O10  
ALA, 010, 4ii8, N, C,   C1   
ALA, 010, 4ii8, N, O,   C
```

file 2:

```
003
00G
010
017
```

I tried to delete lines from file 1 using file 2 with grep:

```
grep -vif file2 file1 >outputFile
```

But because sometimes values in column 6 may be similar with the values in column 2, the file wasn't cleaned up the way I wanted it to be cleaned. How can I delete the rows by comparing the values of column 2 in file 1 with the values in file2?

I have also found such a solution for   `awk`, but it is not useful in my case (file 2 contains about 3000 values):

```
awk -F, '$2 == anyValue' yourFileToFilter
```

Is there any way to modify the command? Or any other solution?

UPDATE

I have also found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097639/how-to-use-awk-to-delete-rows-from-one-csv-some-values-in-a-column-of-which-mat?rq=1) and it seemed to be quite similar to what I needed but it didn't work.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($2 in a)' file2 file1 > file3
```

But the output of file3 looks like that:

```
1    2    3     4  5     6
ALA, 002, 2fv9, H, N,   O6   
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, CA,   C20  
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, CA,   O6   
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, N,   O6   
ALA, 00G, 3fuj, N, CB,   C2   
ALA, 00G, 3fuj, N, CB,   C3   
ALA, 00G, 3fuj, N, N,   O10  
ALA, 010, 4ii8, N, C,   C1   
ALA, 010, 4ii8, N, O,   C
```

UPDATE:

I have just removed all the spaces from file, so now it looks like:

```
ALA,002,2fv9,H,N,O6
ALA,002,2fv9,N,CA,C20
ALA,002,2fv9,N,CA,O6
ALA,002,2fv9,N,N,O6
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,CB,C2
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,CB,C3
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,N,O10
```

And the output is still:

```
ALA,002,2fv9,H,N,O6
ALA,002,2fv9,N,CA,C20
ALA,002,2fv9,N,CA,O6
ALA,002,2fv9,N,N,O6
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,CB,C2
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,CB,C3
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,N,O10
ALA,010,4ii8,N,C,C1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data contains spaces before the field itself, you can set the field separator to a space plus some spaces:

```
awk -F"[, ]+" 'FNR==NR {a[$0]=$0; next} !($2 in a)' f2 f1
```

For your updated input it returns:

```
$ awk -F"[, ]+" 'FNR==NR {a[$0]=$0; next} !($2 in a)' f2 f1
1    2    3     4  5     6
ALA, 002, 2fv9, H, N,   O6   
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, CA,   C20  
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, CA,   O6   
ALA, 002, 2fv9, N, N,   O6
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work for me. Again the output includes everything: 
It can leave 010, but not 002.

Comment: As I said in the answer, do you have "clean" data or every field contains some spaces?

Comment: In file 1 there is a space: `ALA, 002,` between `ALA,` and `002` in file 2 (filter) there are only `\n`

Comment: Of course this won't work, file 2 has no spaces and file 1 has a space before every character. Just change FS to `[, ]+`

Comment: @JID yep, in the answer text I explained that I initally assumed clean data. Then it turned out not to be the case, so I updated with some cleaning. But your suggestion is neater, thanks! I am updating with it.

Comment: I have just removed all the spaces from file1 and left only `,`
Output:
`ALA,002,2fv9,H,N,O6
ALA,002,2fv9,N,CA,C20
ALA,002,2fv9,N,CA,O6
ALA,002,2fv9,N,N,O6
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,CB,C2
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,CB,C3
ALA,00G,3fuj,N,N,O10
ALA,010,4ii8,N,C,C1
ALA,010,4ii8,N,O,C`

Comment: @Anna-Lischen see the updated answer. Also, in comments it is impossible to see formats, so you'd better update your question with the data.

Comment: @Anna-Lischen what exact command did you run to produce the final output you indicate? With `awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$0]=$0; next} !($2 in a)' f2 f1` it is working fine to me.

Comment: `awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$0]=$0; next} !($2 in a)' f2.csv f1.csv ` I have even made new f2 file just in case if f2 was damaged. Now will try to have a look at f1, but there were no problems before.